# How to set concrete culture on page load in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

For example: 
   For multilanguage site created two versions of this site. One site is on default language but another site must use user culture. I want culture changes automatically when I go from one site to another site . (Because, now, after going to my another site I must change language on Ribbon panel). How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to play around with regional settings of a Web you want to have the other culture. use the property

```
SPWeb web;
...
SPRegionalSettings rSettings = new SPRegionalSettings(web);
...
web.RegionalSettings = rSettings;
web.Update();
```